# Calculate the mode of all non-numeric columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to calculate the mode of each column from a dataframe.  I have found similar posts on how to determine the mode of a vector of rows in a dataframe (but most have been with numeric data).

```
df <- data.frame(c("A","B","C","C"), c("A","A","B","C"),c("A","B","B","C"))
colnames(df) <- c("V1","V2","V3")
rownames(df) <- c(1,2,3,4)
df
```

I am using the following function:

```
modefunc <- function(x){
    tabresult <- tabulate(x)
    themode <- which(tabresult == max(tabresult))
    if(sum(tabresult == max(tabresult))>1) themode <- NA
    return(themode)
}

mode.vector <- apply(df, 1, modefunc)
```

Since my dataframe is not numeric, I unfortunately get the following error:

```
Error in tabulate(x) : 'bin' must be numeric or a factor
```

Any assistance with this would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df$mode <- do.call(mapply, c(function(...) names(sort(-table(c(...))))[1], df))`

Comment: Alistare, wow...thanks.  please forgive my naivety, but what do I need to insert into the ... in the two spots?

Comment: Nothing; `...` is a special parameter that will capture whatever is passed to the function—in this case, the values for each row of `df`. A more explicit (but less flexible) way to write the call would be `mapply(function(v1, v2, v3) names(sort(-table(c(v1, v2, v3)))[1]), v1 = df$V1, v2 = df$V2, v3 = df$V3)`

Comment: Alistaire, thanks!!  I guess I am showing my noob status to R and programming.  I appreciate the assistance!!!